# How to wrap locations that are close to each other in a single marker with Mapkit?

Tags: ios, xcode, mkmapview, mapkit

I am looking for a good and fast way to wrap locations that are in a specific range on a MKMapView in a single marker. Clicking on that marker brings you closer to the center point of this locations. You can see what I mean on the picture below.

[mc donalds app - map sample screen](http://i48.tinypic.com/24bt1g6.png)

My first thought was to check a specific pixel range for each marker, hide the ones that are closer than X pixels to each other and get the center of them to create a new marker.

Did anyone of you ever did something similar?

Comment: I've not seen any opensource implementations but you can buy:[`DTClusterMaker`](http://www.cocoanetics.com/parts/dtclustermaker/). Which does what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a demo from WDC 11 or 10 that does exactly that, and coalesces based on proximity, not grid. Much better looking than DTCluster.

Comment: Thank you, found also some other Frameworks like REVClusterMap, SuperPin so far. I just hat to figure out the keyword "clustering" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

After a while of searching an testing, I found several frameworks for this like:

REVClusterMap, SuperPin, DTClusterMaker and a lot more. At the moment I stick with "REMarkerClusterer". It's pretty simple to implement and is free (MIT License)

https://github.com/romaonthego/REMarkerClusterer

Here is a nice article about clustering:
http://applidium.com/en/news/too_many_pins_on_your_map/

If someone else has good frameworks for this in his bookmarks/github-list, please post it here. I sill would like to see them ...